# How do I translate an image based on its height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a tall image, that's in a div that's not as tall. I want to show the whole image by translating it. This is what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/swv0w0em/

```js
 document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
   var element = event.target;
   if (element.classList.contains("myImage") &&
     element.naturalWidth < element.naturalHeight) {
     element.className += " imageScroll";


     //element.style.transform = "translate(0,-" + element.naturalHeight + ")";
     //element.style.mozTransition = "translate(0,-" + element.naturalHeight + ")";
     //element.style.msTransform = "translate(0,-" + element.naturalHeight + ")";
     //element.style.oTransform = "translate(0,-" + element.naturalHeight + ")";
     //element.style.webkitTransform = "translate(0,-" + element.naturalHeight + ")";
   }
 });
 document.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
   var element = event.target;
   if (element.classList.contains("myImage")) {
     element.className = element.className.replace(
       /(?:^|\s)imageScroll(?!\S)/g, ''
     );
   }
 });
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
img {
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}
.imageScroll {
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -350px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -350px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -350px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -350px);
  transform: translate(0, -350px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/800/any" class="myImage" alt="SomeImage">
</div>
```

However, I can't figure out how to translate with the image height. I want the scrolling to stop as soon as the bottom of the image is in view. I don't know how tall the image will be before, so I can't hardcode it in CSS. That why I tried setting the style in JavaScript, but that did not work for me (see the commented out code).

My question: how do I get the image to scroll all the way down on mouseover, and stop scrolling when the bottom of the image is reached? I can't scroll past the height either, or I'll get ugly white space. I'm trying to get this done in pure JavaScript, *without jQuery*. Who can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure CSS you can use percentage unit in the translate, then subtract the height of container using top offset (position absolute):

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.myImage {
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}

.myImage:hover {
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/800/any" class="myImage" alt="SomeImage">
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/h37dLzgf/1/

Comment: Very close! But using that 200px in the calc method causes white spacing. Do you happen to know how to do it without such a hardcoded amount?

Comment: @ohyeah where is the white space? I don't see it

Comment: @ohyeah Make sure to use a css reset

Comment: @Aziz My mistake, I didn't formulate my question well enough: I made the div background red to illustrate the problem. As soon as the height of the div changes, the hardcoded 200px wouldn't work anymore. The div's in my real situation can change size, causing any hardcoded values to fail.

Comment: @ohyeah see update, use position offset instead of calc()

Answer (score 0):

The commented out code has missing "px"

```
 element.style.transform = "translate(0,-" + element.naturalHeight + "px)";
 element.style.mozTransition = "translate(0,-" + element.naturalHeight + "px)";
 element.style.msTransform = "translate(0,-" + element.naturalHeight + "px)";
 element.style.oTransform = "translate(0,-" + element.naturalHeight + "px)";
 element.style.webkitTransform = "translate(0,-" + element.naturalHeight + "px)";
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I changed my code, but that did not solve my problem though.